# Mi FOR se corta al inserta una funcion, C++

Tags: c++, funciones, ordenamiento

Estoy haciendo ordenamiento por inserción, entonces yo quiero imprimir cada cambio que se va haciendo dentro del array `Lista1` en la función `OrdenarPorIncersion`, pero no lo puedo hacer porque si meto la función `MostrameEstaShit` dentro del ciclo for, el ciclo sólo se ejecuta una vez cuando
`i` es `1` pero ya después no sigue.

EJEMPLO como pienso que debería aparecerme

> ```
> 9,5,4,1,5,7,8,4,5,2,6,42,23,12,11 
> 5,9,4,1,5,7,8,4,5,2,6,42,23,12,11
> 4,5,9,1,5,7,8,4,5,2,6,42,23,12,11
> 1,4,5,9,5,7,8,4,5,2,6,42,23,12,11*/
> ```

Y así hasta dejarlos en forma ascendente.

```
int Lista1[n]={9,5,4,1,5,7,8,4,5,2,6,42,23,12,11};
int Lista2;
int j,i;
void MostrameEstaShit(int Lista1[]);
int OrdenarPorIncersion()
{
    cout << "ORDENAMIENTO DE INCERSION" << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if((i>=0 && i<n-1))
        {
            cout << Lista1[i] << ", ";
        }
        else if(i==n-1)
        {
            cout << Lista1[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        Lista2 = Lista1[i];
        j= i-1;
        while((Lista1[j] > Lista2) && (j>=0))
        {
            Lista1[j+1] = Lista1[j];
            j--;
        }
        Lista1[j+1]= Lista2;
        MostrameEstaShit(Lista1); //Aca es mi duda, si dejo la funcion acá, Sólo me imprime los primeros cambios cuando i es 1 y se salta todo el ciclo for.
    }

}
void MostrameEstaShit(int Lista1[])
{
    cout << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if((i>=0 && i<n-1))
        {
            cout << Lista1[i] << ", ";
        }
        else if(i==n-1)
        {
            cout << Lista1[i];
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    OrdenarPorIncersion();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La funcion me agarra solamente al imprimir el array ya estando afuera del ciclo FOR, me coloca todo el array de forma ascendente, pero quisiera que me mostrase el paso a paso, los cambios que se van guardando, pero no entiendo por que no me agarra

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar mejor tu problema? No te estoy entendiendo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es el uso y abuso de variables globales. En C++ se aconseja que las variables tengan el ámbito lo más reducido posible.

Usas la variable `i` como índice en todos tus ciclos `for`, pero compartes esa variable en todos los ciclos de todas las funciones, por lo que cuando llamas a `MostrameEstaShit`, cambias el valor de la variable de manera que cumple la condición de salida del último bucle de la función `OrdenarPorIncersion`.

La solución es dejar de usar variables globales, usa un índice propio en cada bucle `for`.

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

He estado planteándome seriamente no responder a tu pregunta, ya no por la calidad del código (que se corresponde con la calidad de una persona que está aprendiendo) si no por lo desagradable que es leer faltas de ortografía y la pésima elección de nombres en tus funciones. Si quieres que se te tome en serio, empieza por tomarte en serio tu propio código.